# Access static class variable in instance method

Tags: python, class

Say I have class `Test` defined as this:

```
class Test
    test_var = 2
    def test_func():
        print(test_var)
```

I can find out what `test_var` is fine like so:

```
>>> Test.test_var
2
```

...But calling `Test.test_func()` does not work.

```
>>> Test.test_func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in test
NameError: name 'test_var' is not defined
```

If I change `Test.test_func()` like this (note that this is pseudo-code):

```
redef test_func():
    print(Test.test_var)
```

It works fine:

```
>>> Test.test_func()
2
```

...and that makes sense. But how can I make the first example work, *keeping in mind that I want test_func to be an instance method*?

Note that the code posted above is example code, and so typos should be ignored.

Comment: You should post a working example so typos do make a difference. You have this "redef" thing... but it would be more helpful to show what you actually did.

Comment: Your basic problem is that `test_func` is not a class method or instance method so it doesn't know about the class namespace.

Comment: @tdelaney I just re-wrote the class, changing said function. Not how I said it was pseudo-code.

Comment: @tdelaney is `test_func` not a class method?

Comment: No, you need to decorate it with @classmethod and add a parameter to the definition. Its a couple of lines of code so I'll post it as an answer. BTW, is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: @tdelaney 3, as it says in the title. And, actually, this is supposed to be an instance method -- like it says in the question. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always access class-level attributes via the instance, ie `self`, as long as you have not shadowed them with an instance attribute of the same name. So:

```
def test_func(self):
    print(self.test_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either pass self (almost always what you want) to the class method or add a @classmethod or @staticmethod decorator if you don't need self.  Then create an instance of the class and call the test_func method.

```
Examples:
# test_var is an class variable and test_func has a classmethod decorator
>>> class Test:
...     test_var = 2
...     @classmethod
...     def test_func(cls):
...         print(cls.test_var)
... 
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.test_func()
2


# test_var is an class variable and test_func has a staticmethod decorator
>>> class Test:
...     test_var = 2
...     @staticmethod
...     def test_func():
...         print(Test.test_var)
... 
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.test_func()
2

# test_var is an instance variable here
>>> class Test:
...     self.test_var = 2
...     def test_func(self):
...         print(self.test_var)
... 
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.test_func()
2
```

Comment: That's not the issue, the code I posted above is just an example. Good eye, though.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `test_func` is just a function and although its defined in the class namespace, the function itself doesn't know about the class namespace. You want either a regular instance method or a class method.

```
class Test:

    test_var = 2

    def instance_test(self):
        # instance methods will look in self first and class namespace second
        print(self.test_var)

    @classmethod
    def class_test(cls):
        # class methods take the class itself as first argument
        print(cls.test_var)

t = Test()
t.instance_test()
Test.class_test()
```